# Probability of natural events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose  that on  average, two  natural disasters occur per year.   Use  an  appropriate  probability  distribution  to answer the following questions.
>
> (a)  What is the probability that more than four natural disasters will occur in a year?
>
> (b)  What is the probability that no more than six natural disasters will occur in a two-year period?
>
> (c)  How long must a time period be so that the probability of no natural disasters occurring during that time period is at most .1?

So if this is Poisson with $\lambda=2$, then part (a) is $P(X>4)=1-P(X=0,1,2,3,4)?$

For part (b), does $\lambda$ change from $2$ to $4$? So the probability would be $P(X=0,1,2,3,4,5,6)$ with $\lambda=4$?

Comment: Maybe you could use a Poisson distribution.